# How to print a list of Magento 1 product urls in a table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url

I want to query the database for all products with urls starting "afr-" and print them on a cms page in a table. For example, the final printed table would look like:

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-753954329">753954329</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-753954329">https://example.com/afr-753954329</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-498563241">498563241</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-498563241">https://example.com/afr-498563241</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-392736177">392736177</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://example.com/afr-392736177">https://example.com/afr-392736177</a></td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get the url of all products in magento

```
<?php
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
$base_url = Mage::getBaseUrl();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   $product_url = $_product->getProductUrl();
   echo $base_url.$product_url.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('product_url',array('like' =>"afr-"."%"));?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
<?php foreach($product as $_product):?>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl();?>">753954329</a> 
    </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to print all the product URLs starting with "-afr", please try below code:

```
<?php
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();
if (count($_productCollection)) {
    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <?php
        }

        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
            $product_url = $_product->getProductUrl();
            if (stripos($product_url, 'afr-')) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $product_url; ?>"><?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?></a></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $product_url; ?>"><?php echo $product_url; ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        if (count($_productCollection)) {
            ?>
        </tbody></table>
    <?php
}
?>
```